# Weird jump on nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[EDIT] This issue only appears on Chrome and Opera. Firefox and Edge will not see this.

I don't know when and why it starts to happen, so I think I should directly give by website link: [hipark-sez.com](http://hipark-sez.com/). I used bootstrap to create this website.

When I scroll down(mostly upon view port left carousel), I noticed that my top navigation bar created a small jump. like below: 
(you might need to scroll up-and-down several times, this problem sometimes will not appear)[image]

You can see a very-slightly difference in navigation bar height by taking screen shot. But when I watch the navigation bar height value in developer tool, it shows that the navigation bar is 51px(50px height + 1px border) height in either cases. That's quite strange for me.
Even after I specified height of navigation bar as 50px(I think that's unnecessary) or nav tag top position property as 0, the weird jump still remains.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for that. I just tested. This issue only appears on Chrome and Opera. Firefox and Edge don't have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your "navbar-fixed-top" class.

```
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: Seems like this solves the problem! But why this solved the issue? What is hidden by this property?

Comment: The page will 'jump' a little on certain browsers when navigating between short and long pages. This is because the scrollbar gets hidden with short pages and is shown again with longer pages, which makes the page move a little horizontally. And one of the many fixes that this provides is the layers Z-Index problems, animation flickering, and scrolling flickering (which you have)

Comment: But my website has only one single page(long page). There is no horizontal scrollbar at all. It shouldn't have such issue.

Comment: i was refering to section jumps

Comment: Hmmm... Actually I still didn't get it. But seems like I shouldn't spend too much time on this particular issue. Thanks again for your help!